# FFT resolution bandwidth

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have a numpy fft for a large number of samples. How do I reduce the resolution bandwidth, so that it will show me fewer frequency bins, with averaged power output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [lots of ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density_estimation) to estimate the power spectral density of your signal. I would suggest [Welch's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method) (`scipy.signal.welch`).

Answer (score 1):

The bandwidth of each FFT result bin is inversely proportional to the length of the FFT window.  For a wider bandwidth per bin, use a shorter FFT.  If you have more data, then Welch's method can be used with sequential STFT windows to get an average estimate.